# Jekyll pages on GitHub: how does it work?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have my `gh-pages` branch for my project and trying to create some documentation for it.
On GitHub I've read that every time I push things onto the GitHub server, the page is actually fed through to Jekyll.

I haven't installed Jekyll locally. For now, I just want to use GitHub's, and essentially act as a "user".

But... how does it actually work? I've created a `.markdown` page and saw that the equivalent `.html` is created and marked up, like this:

```
---
title: This will be used as the title-tag of the page head
---

Now, let's see.

# Is this working?
```

But... how do I find out how to actually use Jekyll?

I am aware of http://jekyllrb.com/docs/ but I still can't quite figure out what else I can do, and -- more importantly -- how to simply place a markdown file that will be "templated" with the current template?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. You need to install Jekyll locally. It's not hard to do, and it makes life a lot easier. Follow the instructions on http://jekyllrb.com.
2. Your `.markdown` file needs to go in your site's `_posts` directory for Jekyll to transform it into a post. Any files that begin with YAML front matter (the stuff at the top of the file between the dashed lines) are also processed.
3. In order to use a layout, you need to metion it in the page's YAML front matter. So if you changed the example above to:

> ```
> ---
> title: This will be used as the title-tag of the page head
> layout: default
> ---
> ```

Then this page would be generated with the template called `default.html` in your site's `_layouts` folder.

Comment: I was going to answer myself with these exact points. Yes, yes, yes. Thank you!